# Implement Imap inside codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, imap

It works fine using below plugins from xampp

> php_imap.dll

But I want to implement the same inside Codeigniter project

I tried below code from here https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-loop-messages-specific-subject/

```
$unreadEmails = imap_search($connection,
'UNSEEN SUBJECT "Create Ticket" FROM "admin@xyz.com"');
```

But it throws error :

```
Message: Call to undefined method Imap::imap_search()
```

I would like to get all email by unseen, subject contains, on date and if any attachments. Also, mark the email as read after processing.

So how to get source code of the existing IMAP API source code from xampp OR Any sample example to where the code which have config file, IMAP file to place under Codeigniter page. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imap with codeigniter to search with multiple filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59069489/imap-with-codeigniter-to-search-with-multiple-filter)

Comment: It was closed as off topic, so deleted